# HttpClient returns nothing even if the request is successfull

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpclient

I am trying to call an MVC Controller action from an API Controller (both in different applications), I can successfully make a call to the API Controller and returns the result but the controll never gets back to the calling method and PostMan shows the request still pending.

I have this method in my WebApi Controller

```
 [HttpGet]
    public BaseModel GetUserId(string email)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
        {
            return new BaseModel
            {
                success = false,
                message = "invalid username or email."
            };
        }

        var result = _security.GetUserId(email);
        var baseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseModel>(result.Result);

        return baseModel;
    }
```

**_security.GetUserById**

```
 public async Task<string> GetUserId(string userName)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("email",userName)
        });

        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(baseUri + "Account/GetUserId", content);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return result;
        }

        return "";
    }
```

**Here is My API Controller action**

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<BaseModel> GetUserId(string email)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return new BaseModel
            {
                success = false,
                message = "No user exists with the specified email"
            };
        }

        user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(email);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return new BaseModel
            {
                success = false,
                message = "No user exists with the specified username"
            };
        }

        return new BaseModel
        {
            success = true,
            data = user.Id
        };
    }
```